# Evitar repetidos en SELECT MySQL

Tags: mysql, distinct

Tengo la siguiente tabla "`afiliados`" la cual relaciona una persona `idPersona` con una empresa `id_emp`, al poder activar y desactivar la relación tengo que generar un registro por cada relacion entre la empresa y la persona.

```
id-|-idAfiliado-|-idPersona-|-id_emp-|-fechaingreso-|-activo-|-observacion-|-fechadeCarga-|-usuario
2-- 1--------------1-----------9--------2020-09-22-----A-------S/O-------   2020-09-25 18:19:53-------13
3-- 2562-----------2-----------9--------2020-09-22-----A-------S/O--------  2020-10-05 12:19:23-------13
6-- 2562-----------2-----------10-------2020-09-17-----P-------S/O-------   2020-10-05 12:12:01-------13
11--2563-----------4-----------3--------2020-09-11-----A-------S/O-------   2020-09-28 20:17:50-------13
12--2564-----------5-----------3--------2020-09-18-----A-------S/O-------   2020-09-28 20:18:09-------13
13--2565-----------26----------14-------2020-10-10-----A-------S/O-------   2020-10-03 18:25:48-------13
16--2----------- --8-----------33-------2020-10-05-----P-------S/O-------   2020-10-05 12:11:56-------117
```

El caso es que quiero listar todos los campos, pero evitando repetir los `idPersona`, que solo me traiga el primero. Intente con:

```
SELECT DISTINCT afiliado.idPersona,
afiliado.idAfiliado,
afiliado.numAfiliado,
afiliado.id_emp,
afiliado.fingresoAfiliado,
afiliado.estadoAfiliado,
persona.nombrePersona,
persona.idTdni,
persona.documentoPersona,
FROM
afiliado
RIGHT JOIN persona ON afiliado.idPersona = persona.idPersona
```

Pero continua devolviendo los campos repetidos.
Cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo?
La salida deseada es:

```
id-|-idAfiliado-|-idPersona-|-id_emp-|-fechaingreso-|-activo-|-observacion-|-fechadeCarga-------|-usuario
2-- 1--------------1-----------9--------2020-09-22-----A-------S/O-------   2020-09-25 18:19:53-------13
3-- 2562-----------2-----------9--------2020-09-22-----A-------S/O--------  2020-10-05 12:19:23-------13
11--2563-----------4-----------3--------2020-09-11-----A-------S/O-------   2020-09-28 20:17:50-------13
12--2564-----------5-----------3--------2020-09-18-----A-------S/O-------   2020-09-28 20:18:09-------13
13--2565-----------26----------14-------2020-10-10-----A-------S/O-------   2020-10-03 18:25:48-------13
16--2----------- --8-----------33-------2020-10-05-----P-------S/O-------   2020-10-05 12:11:56-------117
```

Comment: El id 2562 se repite porque están con diferente id, empresa y estado. Entonces no va a funcionar el `distinct`, si agregas la condición del estado obtendrías uno solo.

Comment: Puedes poner una salida deseada? El id 2562 no parece ser una tupla única

Comment: Ahi agregue la salida deseada

Comment: Mira esto: en la tabla el id 3 y 6 ( linea 2 y 3 ) del query original, los campos id empleado son 9 y 10 esos genera dos registros diferentes, cual es el criterio que se debe tener en esas columnas? el mayor? el menor?

Comment: Y de los campos repetidos cual es que va escoger basándote en que criterio pq alomejor tienes 10 campos y tienes que determinar de esos 10 con cual te quedas quizá podría ser el más reciente o el más antiguo o otro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, lo que buscas es listar de cada `persona` la última fila de `afiliado`, según su `fechadeCarga`. Con este criterio, ubicar la última fila de `afiliado` por `idPersona` se podría hacer así:

```
SELECT a1.*
       FROM afiliado a1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT  idPersona,
                           MAX(fechadeCarga) as UltimafechadeCarga
                           FROM afiliado
                           GROUP BY idPersona
          ) a2
          ON a1.idPersona = a2.idPersona
          AND a1.fechadeCarga = a2.UltimafechadeCarga
```

Importante: usamos `fechadeCarga` para determinar el orden, por que según el `id` que muestras, no parece seguir el criterio, que el mayor de estos se corresponde con la fila más nueva.

Luego, puedes integrar esta consulta a la principal:

```
SELECT  a.idPersona,
        a.idAfiliado,
        a.numAfiliado,
        a.id_emp,
        a.fingresoAfiliado,
        a.estadoAfiliado,
        p.nombrePersona,
        p.idTdni,
        p.documentoPersona    
        FROM persona p
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT a1.*
                        FROM afiliado a1
                        INNER JOIN (SELECT  idPersona,
                                            MAX(fechadeCarga) as UltimafechadeCarga
                                            FROM afiliado
                                            GROUP BY idPersona
                        ) a2
                        ON a1.idPersona = a2.idPersona
                        AND a1.fechadeCarga = a2.UltimafechadeCarga
            ) a
            ON a.idPersona = p.idPersona
```